How do I use gdb with RISC-V Virtual Platform? [riscv]
I compiled and ran the VP from this repository.
https://github.com/vherdt/riscv-vp
I am able to run the firmware codes in simple-sensor with .
My question is, is it possible to use gdb+Eclipse with that VP model and debug the firmware codes like an IDE?
userid@linux:/work/riscv-vp/sw/simple-sensor$ riscv-vp main

        SystemC 2.3.3-Accellera --- Apr  1 2024 10:45:52
        Copyright (c) 1996-2018 by all Contributors,
        ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
qdrhxdpkutiulnauplobelmkrdbmqsiivbpthffdapyncyhtkyvqljaeoereybnu
fepmjuplkpzooiiaifqtqsyeypjxqyrveijqcbboqcdgllitqyngtnmrcvouvhsa
pbqsctivwlbjykcqkrydelxgildetvgkyycdtnypybyzldpyuodzzahhoknjfvte

Info: /OSCI/SystemC: Simulation stopped by user.
=[ core : 0 ]===========================
simulation time: 15135010 ns
zero (x0) =        0
ra   (x1) =    103c4
sp   (x2) =  1fffffc
gp   (x3) =        0
tp   (x4) =        0
t0   (x5) =  2010000
t1   (x6) = ffffffff
t2   (x7) =        0
s0/fp(x8) =        0
s1   (x9) =        0


I searched but that topic is very specific and didn't yield good reply.
